# What is a suitable Gear Range for Biking on Flat Rail Trails

Tags: gears

My wife and I are 70 and are planning a purchase for relaxed riding exclusively on smooth (packed cinder/crushed stone) rail trails. We’re looking at comfort bikes like the Jamis Hudson Sport and the Giant/Liv Sedona with a preference for 7 speeds. Our area is hilly but the rail trails are not.

Thoughts on the choice of bikes and the preference of 7 speeds instead of 21 for this type of riding?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: We don't normally do specific product recommendation by name, but I have no problem with pointing out that the Jamis Hudson Sport has that "one brake lever" system which loses all your redundancy.  I'd never recommend such a braking system for anyone of any level, ever.

Even a one-handed cyclist would be better off using a single lever with dual independent brake systems, not that ridiculous Sure Stop idea.

In my country, such a system would be illegal for sale.  Says it all really.
(comment cos not an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Comfort oriented hybrid bikes are good for recreational riding on smooth prepared trails without steep hills.

7 speed bikes are simpler, but without a choice of front sprockets you will want to be sure that the gear range they offer suits you. Getting a good test ride on any bike you are considering is recommended.

One thing I would avoid is front suspension. At the price range of the bikes you mention they don't provide much damping but do add weight.